# Can I setup a custom response header to all my lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using lambda with CORS, and I currently have to setup manually for every response in every lambda function the following header:

```
const response = {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
      },
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify(params.Item),
};
```

Is there a way to setup the headers as a default response for all my lambdas? Perhaps in API Gateway or somewhere else so I don't have to manually add it for every single response?

Answer (score 1):

You should set up CORS handing at the API gateway instead. That way you don't have to pay for your lambda to handle CORS OPTION requests.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 1):

API gateway can help achieve it, especially when we have mostly static response headers to add.

(1) go to resources > 'method response'... add your response headers for the 200 (OK) HTTP status (first image)

[image: AWS API Gateway, add custom response headers]

(2) go to resources > 'integration response'... add mappings to your values (second image)

[image: eAWS API Gateway, add custom response headers]

for dynamic data in the response headers, lambda works best